# Can't download the .mp3 file from an URL after a few days

Tags: iphone

I want to download a .mp3 file on a Website with NSSURLConnection on IPhone,

This .mp3 URL of the file is:

http://dl.mp3.kapsule.info/fsfsdfdsfdserwrwq3/fc90613208cc3f16ae6d6ba05d21880c/4b5244f0/b/7e/b7e80afa18d06fdd3dd9f9fa44b51fc0.mp3?filename=Every-Day-I-Love-You.mp3

When I built my app, it run OK. My app downloaded the .mp3 file successful and then played it. However, after a few days, I run my app again, the app can't downloaded the .mp3 file.

How can I download the .mp3 file all the time?

Thank you very much.

Comment: The URL no longer works.  You need a different URL.

Comment: The site is no longer offering the mp3 at that URL.  That's not a programming issue, that's what they do.  Take it up with them.

Comment: Is the URL hardcoded? Then you could better include the MP3 file in the bundle.

Answer (score 2):

It is highly possible that this website generates URLs in a manner that stops linking directly to the MP3 file. A temporary address is generated when you request an MP3 and expires after a certain length of time. This practice is generally used to stop hot-linking / bandwidth stealing and I have implemented it on several websites.

Essentially, they don't want you to link directly to this file, so they automatically "move" the file (I imagine they don't physically move the file, but instead only give out the "public" address, which they can expire regularly.)

Comment: 99.99% sure that's whats happening here.